# Setting a date/time using Symfony PHPUnit bridge ClockMock

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I can't figure out how to set the date/time used by `ClockMock` class. In the documentation:

> Additionally the function `date()` is mocked so it uses the mocked time if no timestamp is specified. Other functions with an optional timestamp parameter that defaults to `time()` will still use the system time instead of the mocked time.

This is what I attempted to do:

```
class Foo
{
    public function now(): string {
        return date('Y-m-d');
    }
}


/**
 * @covers Foo
 * @group time-sensitive
 */
class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @covers Foo::now
     */
    public function testNow(): void {
        ClockMock::register(Foo::class);
        ClockMock::withClockMock('2019-01-01');

        $f = new Foo();
        static::assertSame('2019-01-01', $f->now());
    }
}
```

The assertion is still failing with the actual date being today's date.

I even tried calling `date('Y-m-d')` inside the assertion in the test class but it is still returning today's date instead of the mocked date.

How do I set the mocked date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to the source code (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Bridge/PhpUnit/ClockMock.php#L28) the parameter to `ClockMock::withClockMock()` expects as its first parameter a number (checked by `is_numeric`, converted to float) and use that as its timestamp. If it's not a number, it will use the current microtime as timestamp.

So your code probably should be:

```
ClockMock::withClockMock(date_create('2019-01-01')->getTimestamp());
```